# What are the alternatives to Quickbooks SDK for pulling data from and to Quickbooks Desktop in Python Django on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

How can I easily integrate Quickbooks (QBO and Desktop) with Python

I am developing a web-based syetem Using Django Framework. Running Ubuntu 22.04, Unfortunately the OS am using does not support Quickbooks SDK

How can I pull data from and to the Quickbooks Desktop running on a network